# Where can I find a Gherkin language spec/guide?

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I'm trying to find out all available syntax/format in Gherkin, such as about multiline argument and everything else I don't know yet.

After digging Google search results though, it seems that the comprehensive guide is located in [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki):

I thought that was pretty good, and [it](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then) has a link to a page that supposedly describes multiline arguments and others, but it took me to 404 Not found instead =(.

Does anybody have better suggestion on where to read up about this?

EDIT: to stress that I've done so many Google searches. It gives some rather good sites like [specflow](http://www.specflow.org) and [cuke4ninja](http://www.cuke4ninja.com), but none of them gives comprehensive description of Gherkin. If someone finds an answer to this through Google search, then please feel free to call me a Googling noob and suggestions to improve are welcome.

Comment: You're in a pickle, for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best place I know of to understand the Gherkin language is the wiki that you link to. However, as you found there's sometimes a broken link there. What I tend to do is to click the "Pages" link at the bottom of the gray bar with all the GitHub links in it. That takes you to an alphabetical listing of all the wiki pages, including [this one for Multiline Step Arguments](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Multiline-Step-Arguments).

Comment: ugh.. @Jason's link 404's, but theres some good stuff at https://cukes.info/docs/reference#step-arguments , though there are a number of sections marked #todo

Answer (score 6):

It's not free, but [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) has a complete guide to Gherkin.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of the cucumber book.

Answer (score 2):

Gherkin syntax can be checked on [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/guides/1.gherkin.html) website where you can also check examples for PHP language.

Answer (score 2):

The [BNF grammar](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/wiki/BNF) understood by Cucumbe is available online. The JBehave project also published an [EBNF grammar](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/grammar.html) of the language which can be used for writing `.feature` files.

Comment: Where are those Treetop files in cucumber codebase? Having hard time to locate them.

Comment: The Gherkin BNF grammar page seems to have disappeared off the wiki, sadly.  However the Gherkin grammar in .berp format can be found in the source: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/39201f20ffe5aef5eedc491a0466f0c67e2a8d0b/gherkin.berp